# Unpinning the accepted answer from the top of the list of answers in Magento Stackexchange

Tags: discussion, answers, accepted-answer, stackexchange

I think community should have a discussion about this topic -
[Unpinning the accepted answer from the top of the list of answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369568/unpinning-the-accepted-answer-from-the-top-of-the-list-of-answers)

I think it is a good change as a lot of the old questions have marked answers which no longer reflect best practices.

Comment: Note: Until the answer gets voted on, the Community bot will continue bumping this question. (Specifically, it'll keep happening while the top-voted answer on the question has a score of 0.)

Answer (score 2):

I agree that unpinning the answer might be a good idea here. This would be especially helpful on Questions that are asked in a manner not pertaining to a particular Magento version, but were e.g. answered for Magento 1.